# UserControls and List of Objects in Grid WPF

Tags: wpf, list

I want to show in WPF a grid (no matter if grid, datagrid etc.). Every cell should be filled by a usercontrol. The usercontrol gets their content by an object.

So in the beginning I there's an object list List. The number of columns of the grid is given. The number of rows results from the number of objects in the list (this is not my problem). Every object can be shown in a usercontrol.

MyObject1 + MyUserControl -> Cell1

MyObject2 + MyUserControl -> Cell2

...

[Here's a picture from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDISw.png), to show, what it should look like.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Nothing really useful, cause I didn't know how to begin. But the answer below helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need grid, you should use ItemsControl with WrapPanel as ItemsPanel.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourItemTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

<DataTemplate x:Key="YourItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                <Button Content="Remove item" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```